# How to allocate 16byte memory aligned data

Tags: c, memory, sse, icc

I am trying to implement SSE vectorization on a piece of code for which I need my 1D array to be 16 byte memory aligned. However, I have tried several ways to allocate 16byte memory aligned data but it ends up being 4byte memory aligned.

I have to work with the Intel icc compiler.
This is a sample code I am testing with:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  void error(char *str)
  {
   printf("Error:%s\n",str);
   exit(-1);
  }

  int main()
  {
   int i;
   //float *A=NULL;
   float *A = (float*) memalign(16,20*sizeof(float));

   //align
   // if (posix_memalign((void **)&A, 16, 20*sizeof(void*)) != 0)
   //   error("Cannot align");

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
       printf("&A[%d] = %p\n",i,&A[i]);

        free(A);

         return 0;
   }
```

This is the output I get:

```
 &A[0] = 0x11fe010
 &A[1] = 0x11fe014
 &A[2] = 0x11fe018
 &A[3] = 0x11fe01c
 &A[4] = 0x11fe020
 &A[5] = 0x11fe024
 &A[6] = 0x11fe028
 &A[7] = 0x11fe02c
 &A[8] = 0x11fe030
 &A[9] = 0x11fe034
 &A[10] = 0x11fe038
 &A[11] = 0x11fe03c
 &A[12] = 0x11fe040
 &A[13] = 0x11fe044
 &A[14] = 0x11fe048
 &A[15] = 0x11fe04c
 &A[16] = 0x11fe050
 &A[17] = 0x11fe054
 &A[18] = 0x11fe058
 &A[19] = 0x11fe05c
```

It is 4byte aligned everytime, i have used both memalign, posix memalign. Since I am working on Linux, I cannot use _mm_malloc neither can I use _aligned_malloc.
I get a memory corruption error when I try to use _aligned_attribute (which is suitable for gcc alone I think).

Can anyone assist me in accurately generating 16byte memory aligned data for icc on linux platform.

Comment: How do you know it is 4 byte aligned, simply because printf is only outputting 4 bytes at a time?  Just because you are using the memalign routine, you are putting it into a float type.  When you print using printf, it knows how to process through it's primitive type (float).

Comment: Why can't you use "_mm_malloc" on Linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The memory you allocate is 16-byte aligned. See:
`&A[0] = 0x11fe010`
But in an array of `float`, each element is 4 bytes, so the second is 4-byte aligned.

You can use an array of structures, each containing a single float, with the `aligned` attribute:

```
struct x {
    float y;
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
struct x *A = memalign(...);
```

Comment: I think `__attribute__` is a GCC's builtin, not available for ICC.

Comment: @Benoit, GCC specific indeed, but I think ICC does support it. [See here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/compilers/intel_linux_compiler_compatibility_with_gnu_compilers.pdf)

Comment: @Benoit: If you need to align a struct on 16, just add 12 bytes of padding at the end...

Comment: @VladLazarenko, Works, but not nice and portable. If, in some compiler, `float` is changed, you'll have bad alignment again.

Comment: @ugoren: For that reason you could add a static assertion, disable padding for a structure, etc.  `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` doesn't really work with gcc, and is not portable either.

Comment: @VladLazarenko, the attribute doesn't work with GCC?! Maybe you meant "works only with GCC". It isn't really portable, but the compiler will let you know when it doesn't work. An assertion is an alternative. In general, I always prefer to tell the compiler what I want as accurately as possible, and in this case I want alignment, not padding (I'll get padding anyway, but it isn't what I want).

Comment: @ugoren: No, I mean it doesn't work with GCC in some cases. I.e. if allocated on stack, or alignment is less than minimum alignment requirements, etc. Plus there are still open bugs for that attribute. It is as much reliable as adding padding yourself.

Comment: On the stack, nothing can make an allocation be aligned beyond the stack's alignment (8 bytes normally). But he allocates dynamically. I don't see how the minimum required alignment is relevant. And I've been using this attribute a lot with GCC 3 and 4, and never met such a bug.

Answer (score 7):

The address returned by `memalign` function is `0x11fe010`, which is a multiple of `0x10`. So the function is doing a right thing. This also means that your array *is* properly aligned on a 16-byte boundary. What you are doing later is printing an address of every next element of type `float` in your array. Since `float` size is exactly 4 bytes in your case, every next address will be equal to the previous one +4. For instance, `0x11fe010 + 0x4 = 0x11FE014`. Of course, address `0x11FE014` is not a multiple of `0x10`. If you were to align all floats on 16 byte boundary, then you will have to waste `16 / 4 - 1` bytes per element. Double-check the requirements for the intrinsics that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, both `memalign` and `posix_memalign` are doing their job.

```
&A[0] = 0x11fe010
```

This is aligned to 16 byte.

```
&A[1] = 0x11fe014
```

When you do `&A[1]` you are telling the compiller to add one position to a `float` pointer. It will unavoidably lead to:

```
&A[0] + sizeof( float ) = 0x11fe010 + 4 = 0x11fe014
```

If you intend to have **every** element inside your vector aligned to 16 bytes, you should consider declaring an array of structures that are 16 byte wide.

```
struct float_16byte
{
    float data;
    float padding[ 3 ];
}
    A[ ELEMENT_COUNT ];
```

Then you must allocate memory for `ELEMENT_COUNT` (20, in your example) variables:

```
struct float_16byte *A = ( struct float_16byte * )memalign( 16, ELEMENT_COUNT * sizeof( struct float_16byte ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Hardware_significance_of_alignment_requirements):

```
Example: get a 12bit aligned 4KBytes buffer with malloc()

// unaligned pointer to large area
void *up=malloc((1<<13)-1);
// well aligned pointer to 4KBytes
void *ap=aligntonext(up,12);

where aligntonext() is meant as: 
move p to the right until next well aligned address if
not correct already. A possible implementation is

// PSEUDOCODE assumes uint32_t p,bits; for readability
// --- not typesafe, not side-effect safe
#define alignto(p,bits) (p>>bits<<bits)
#define aligntonext(p,bits) alignto((p+(1<<bits)-1),bits)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe your code is correct and is suitable for Intel SSE code. When you load data into an XMM register, I believe the processor can only load 4 contiguous float data from main memory with the first one aligned by 16 byte.

In short, I believe what you have done is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you could also used this in VS.

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct x {
    long long a;
    long long b;
    char c;
};
```

instead of this

```
struct x {
    float y;
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```