# Segmentation fault while working with SSE intrinsics due to incorrect memory alignment

Tags: c, memory, sse, icc

I am working with SSE intrinsics for the first time and I am encountering a segmentation fault even after ensuring 16byte memory alignment. This post is an extension to my earlier question:

[How to allocate 16byte memory aligned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084468/how-to-allocate-16byte-memory-aligned-data)

This is how I have declared my array:

```
  float *V = (float*) memalign(16,dx*sizeof(float));
```

When I try to do this:

```
  __m128 v_i = _mm_load_ps(&V[i]); //It works
```

But when I do this:

```
  __m128 u1 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(i-1)]); //There is a segmentation fault
```

But if I do :

```
  __m128 u1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i-1)]); //It works again
```

However I want to eliminate using `_mm_loadu_ps` and want to make it work using `_mm_load_ps` only.

I am working with the Intel icc compiler.

How do I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

using both operations in the following code:

```
  void FDTD_base (float *V, float *U, int dx, float c0, float c1, float c2, float c3,     float c4)
    {
       int i, j, k;
                    for (i = 4; i < dx-4; i++)
                    {

                            U[i] = (c0 * (V[i]) //center
                                    + c1 * (V[(i-1)] + V[(i+1)] )
                                    + c2 * (V[(i-2)] + V[(i+2)] )
                                    + c3 * (V[(i-3)] + V[(i+3)] )
                                    + c4 * (V[(i-4)] + V[(i+4)] ));
                    }

       }
```

SSE version:

```
         for (i=4; i < dx-4; i+=4)
        {
            v_i = _mm_load_ps(&V[i]);
            __m128 center = _mm_mul_ps(v_i,c0_i);

            __m128 u1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i-1)]);
            u2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i+1)]);

            u3 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i-2)]);
            u4 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i+2)]);

            u5 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i-3)]);
            u6 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i+3)]);

            u7 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(i-4)]);
            u8 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(i+4)]);

            __m128 tmp1 = _mm_add_ps(u1,u2);
            __m128 tmp2 = _mm_add_ps(u3,u4);
            __m128 tmp3 = _mm_add_ps(u5,u6);
            __m128 tmp4 = _mm_add_ps(u7,u8);

            __m128 tmp5 = _mm_mul_ps(tmp1,c1_i);
            __m128 tmp6 = _mm_mul_ps(tmp2,c2_i);
            __m128 tmp7 = _mm_mul_ps(tmp3,c3_i);
            __m128 tmp8 = _mm_mul_ps(tmp4,c4_i);

            __m128 tmp9 = _mm_add_ps(tmp5,tmp6);
            __m128 tmp10 = _mm_add_ps(tmp7,tmp8);

            __m128 tmp11 = _mm_add_ps(tmp9,tmp10);
            __m128 tmp12 = _mm_add_ps(center,tmp11);

            _mm_store_ps(&U[i], tmp12);
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this using only `_mm_load_ps()` ?

Comment: What is `sizeof(float)` on your architecture?

Comment: @ecatmur: I am working on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question; there are plenty of different 64-bit ABIs.

Comment: @ecatmur: `float` is, by definition, always 32 bits. This is not architecture-dependent.

Comment: Tip: you can check and print the variables' alignment with `alignof` or by looking at the addresses with a debugger. If the address ends with '0', it's 16B aligned, else, if it ends with '0,4,8,c' it's 4B aligned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `sizeof(float)` is 4, only every fourth entry in `V` will be properly aligned. Remember that `_mm_load_ps` loads four floats at a time. The argument, i.e. the pointer to the first float, needs to be aligned to 16 bytes.

I'm assuming that in your example `i` is a multiple of four, otherwise `_mm_load_ps(&V[i])` would fail.

**Update**

This is how I would suggest implementing the above sliding window example using aligned loads and shuffles:

```
__m128 v_im1;
__m128 v_i = _mm_load_ps( &V[0] );
__m128 v_ip1 = _mm_load_ps( &V[4] );

for ( i = 4 ; i < dx ; i += 4 ) {

    /* Get the three vectors in this 'frame'. */
    v_im1 = v_i; v_i = v_ip1; v_ip1 = _mm_load_ps( &V[i+4] );

    /* Get the u1..u8 from the example code. */
    __m128 u3 = _mm_shuffle_ps( v_im1 , v_i , 3 + (4<<2) + (0<<4) + (1<<6) );
    __m128 u4 = _mm_shuffle_ps( v_i , v_ip1 , 3 + (4<<2) + (0<<4) + (1<<6) );

    __m128 u1 = _mm_shuffle_ps( u3 , v_i , 1 + (2<<2) + (1<<4) + (2<<6) );
    __m128 u2 = _mm_shuffle_ps( v_i , u4 , 1 + (2<<2) + (1<<4) + (2<<6) );

    __m128 u5 = _mm_shuffle_ps( v_im1 , u3 , 1 + (2<<2) + (1<<4) + (2<<6) );
    __m128 u6 = _mm_shuffle_ps( u4 , v_ip1 , 1 + (2<<2) + (1<<4) + (2<<6) );

    __m128 u7 = v_im1;
    __m128 u8 = v_ip1;

    /* Do your computation and store. */
    ...

    }
```

Note that this is a bit tricky since `_mm_shuffle_ps` can only take two values from each argument, which is why we first need to make `u3` and `u4` in order to re-use them for the other values with different overlaps.

Note also that the values `u1`, `u3`, and `u5` can also be recovered from `u2`, `u4` and `u6` in the previous iteration.

Note, finally, that I have *not verified the above code*! Read the documentation for `_mm_shuffle_ps` and check that the third argument, the selector, is correct for each case.

Comment: Pedro: you are right. i is a multiple of 4 in my example. But how do I overcome the segmentation fault?

Comment: @Hello_PG: That depends on what you want to do. Do you have to do SIMD operations on all elements of `V` in groups of four, e.g. `V[0..3]`, `V[4..7]`, `V[8..11]`? Or do you have a sliding window of length four, e.g. `v[0..3]`, `V[1..4]`, `V[2..5]`? In the former case, you could just use a `for` loop over `i`, incrementing `i` by `4` in each iteration. In the latter case, you're stuck with the less efficient unaligned `_mm_loadu_ps`.

Comment: My code does involve a sliding window concept. Basically it is a 1D stencil , that requires me to track the neighboring 4 elements. I updated the code using both _mm_load_ps and _mm_loadu_ps..Please find the code in my updated post. Is this the best way to tackle it?

Comment: @Hello_PG: No, this is probably not the best way, since you're reading the same data four times. Your best bet is probably to do `v1 = _mm_load_ps(&V[i])` and `v2 = _mm_load_ps(&V[i+4])` and then construct the vectors for `i+1`, `i+2` and `i+3` using the `_mm_shuffle_ps(v1,v2,...)` instruction. Note that in each iteration, the `v2` from the previous iteration becomes your new `v1`.