# Vectorizing a 2D stencil using SSE intrinsics

Tags: c, memory, sse, icc

I am trying to vectorize a 2D stencil using only aligned, loads and stores. For this I want to essentially use `_mm_load_ps` and `_mm_shuffle_ps` to obtain the desired addresses.

My scalar version of code is:

```
    void FDTD_base (float *V, float *U, int dx, int dy, float c0, float c1, float c2, float c3, float c4)
    {
    int i, j, k;

            for (j = 4; j < dy-4; j++)
            {
                    for (i = 4; i < dx-4; i++)
                    {

                            U[j*dx+i] = (c0 * (V[j*dx+i]) //center
                                    + c1 * (V[j*dx+(i-1)] + V[(j-1)*dx+i] + V[j*dx+(i+1)] + V[(j+1)*dx+i] )
                                    + c2 * (V[j*dx+(i-2)] + V[(j-2)*dx+i] + V[j*dx+(i+2)] + V[(j+2)*dx+i] )
                                    + c3 * (V[j*dx+(i-3)] + V[(j-3)*dx+i] + V[j*dx+(i+3)] + V[(j+3)*dx+i] )
                                    + c4 * (V[j*dx+(i-4)] + V[(j-4)*dx+i] + V[j*dx+(i+4)] + V[(j+4)*dx+i] ));

                    }
            }

      }
```

My vector see version of code so far:

```
     for (j = 4; j < dy-4; j++)
    {
            for (i = 4; i < dx-4; i+=4)
            {
                    __m128 b = _mm_load_ps(&V[j*dx+i]);
                    center = _mm_mul_ps(b,c0_i);
                    a = _mm_load_ps(&V[j*dx+(i-4)]);
                    c = _mm_load_ps(&V[j*dx+(i+4)]);

                    d = _mm_load_ps(&V[(j-4)*dx+i]);
                    e = _mm_load_ps(&V[(j+4)*dx+i]);

                    u_i2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(a,b,_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,3,2));//i-2
                    u_i6 = _mm_shuffle_ps(b,c,_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,3,2));//i+2

                    u_i1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(u_i2,b,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//i-1
                    u_i5 = _mm_shuffle_ps(b,u_i6,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//i+1

                    u_i3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(a,u_i2,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//i-3
                    u_i7 = _mm_shuffle_ps(u_i6,c,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//i+3

                    u_i4 = a; //i-4
                    u_i8 = c; //i+4
```

Can someone help me in obtaining the positions of j-1,j+1 .....j-4,j+4.

This does not work:

```
                    u_j2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(d,b,_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,3,2));//j-2 (this is incorrect)
                    u_j6 = _mm_shuffle_ps(b,e,_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,3,2));//j+2

                    u_j1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(u_j2,b,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//j-1
                    u_j5 = _mm_shuffle_ps(b,u_j6,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//j+1

                    u_j3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(d,u_j2,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//j-3
                    u_j7 = _mm_shuffle_ps(u_j6,e,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,2,1));//j+3

                    u_j4 = d; //j-4 (this is fine)
                    u_j8 = e; //j+4
```

I need help only to determine how to obtain `(j-1)*dx+i`,`(j+1)*dx+1` ..... `(j-4)*dx+i` and `(j+4)*dx+i` without using unaligned loads.

As a potential solution i thought of adding a displacement `3*dx` to addresses stored in `d` to obtain `(j-1)*dx+i`. And Subtracting a displacement of `3*dx` to address stored in `e` to obtain `(j+1)*dx+i`.
Similarly adding `2*dx` to address of `d` to obtain `j-2` and so on. But I dont know to implement this strategy using the SSE intrinsics.

Please help. I am using the Intel icc compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault while working with SSE intrinsics due to incorrect memory alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085924/segmentation-fault-while-working-with-sse-intrinsics-due-to-incorrect-memory-ali)

Comment: @Paul: Not exactly. I am trying to determine how to use `mm_shuffle_ps` when there is a stride value involved. The previous post was for a 1D sliding window. This is a 2D sliding window, which has a new dimension which makes it more complicated. Any assistance will be very helpful

Comment: Are all of your constraints firm? E.g., absolutely no unaligned loads and stores? There are other ways of expressing the same computation that are quite efficient (esp. on Nehalem and later Intel CPUs), but do require unaligned loads and stores.

Answer (score 0):

"Can someone help me in obtaining the positions of j-1,j+1 .....j-4,j+4." - these do not require a shuffle; they are already aligned with your SIMD lanes.

```
u_j2 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(j-2)*dx+i]); 
u_j6 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(j+2)*dx+i]); 
u_j1 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(j-1)*dx+i]); 
u_j5 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(j+1)*dx+i]); 
// and so forth
```

You *definitely* cannot these from the variables you have labelled as `d` and `e` by any possible rearrangement because the values in `d` (for example) are `V[j-4, i], V[j-4, i+1], V[j-4, i+2], V[j-4, i+3]`, and you cannot get `V[j-2, i]` out of that.

Tip: Think in terms of SIMD lanes; that makes it clear that you need to rearrange horizontally but not vertically.

Tip: Consider what happens when the inner loop counter increments (`i+=4`).  What was u_i5 (`V[j, i+1..i+5]`) in the last loop is now u_i3 (`V[j, i-3..i+1]`) in the current loop.  You are calculating each offset version of the data in your row at least twice.  You can probably unroll the loop a few times and avoid doing all the extra work.

Tip: Why not use AVX?  Use _mm256_permute_ps (and _mm256_permute2f128_ps if needed) to shuffle, and the corresponding load instructions.  It will be almost twice faster since you have twice as wide SIMD registers and most AVX instructions still take only one cycle on modern CPU, same as SSE instructions.

Comment: @Hello_PG: Please have a look and let me know if this answers your question. If it does, I would appreciate it if you accept and upvote. Thanks!