# Memory alignment for SSE in C++, _aligned_malloc equivalent?

Tags: c++, g++, malloc, sse, memory-alignment

I was wondering how I could turn this C code into C++ for memory alignment.

`float *pResult = (float*) _aligned_malloc(length * sizeof(float), 16);`

I did look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084468/how-to-allocate-16byte-memory-aligned-data) and then I tried this 
`float *pResult = (float*) __attribute__((aligned(16)));`

and this

`float *pResult = __attribute__((aligned(16)));`

but both gave similar errors.

```
error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'|
error: expected ',' or ';' before '__attribute__'|
```

Complete code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <xmmintrin.h>  // Need this for SSE compiler intrinsics
#include <math.h>       // Needed for sqrt in CPU-only version
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Starting calculation...\n");

    const int length = 64000;

    // We will be calculating Y = Sin(x) / x, for x = 1->64000

    // If you do not properly align your data for SSE instructions, you may take a huge performance hit.
    float *pResult = (float*) __attribute__((aligned(16))); // align to 16-byte for SSE
    __m128 x;
    __m128 xDelta = _mm_set1_ps(4.0f);      // Set the xDelta to (4,4,4,4)
    __m128 *pResultSSE = (__m128*) pResult;


    const int SSELength = length / 4;

    for (int stress = 0; stress < 100000; stress++) // lots of stress loops so we can easily use a stopwatch
    {
#define TIME_SSE    // Define this if you want to run with SSE
#ifdef TIME_SSE
        x = _mm_set_ps(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f); // Set the initial values of x to (4,3,2,1)
        for (int i=0; i < SSELength; i++)
        {
            __m128 xSqrt = _mm_sqrt_ps(x);
            // Note! Division is slow. It's actually faster to take the reciprocal of a number and multiply
            // Also note that Division is more accurate than taking the reciprocal and multiplying

#define USE_DIVISION_METHOD
#ifdef USE_FAST_METHOD
            __m128 xRecip = _mm_rcp_ps(x);
            pResultSSE[i] = _mm_mul_ps(xRecip, xSqrt);
#endif //USE_FAST_METHOD
#ifdef USE_DIVISION_METHOD
            pResultSSE[i] = _mm_div_ps(xSqrt, x);
#endif  // USE_DIVISION_METHOD

            // NOTE! Sometimes, the order in which things are done in SSE may seem reversed.
            // When the command above executes, the four floating elements are actually flipped around
            // We have already compensated for that flipping by setting the initial x vector to (4,3,2,1) instead of (1,2,3,4)

            x = _mm_add_ps(x, xDelta);  // Advance x to the next set of numbers
        }
#endif  // TIME_SSE
#ifndef TIME_SSE
        float xFloat = 1.0f;
        for (int i=0 ; i < length; i++)
        {
            pResult[i] = sqrt(xFloat) / xFloat; // Even though division is slow, there are no intrinsic functions like there are in SSE
            xFloat += 1.0f;
        }
#endif  // !TIME_SSE
    }

    // To prove that the program actually worked
    for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("Result[%d] = %f\n", i, pResult[i]);
    }

    // Results for my particular system
    // 23.75 seconds for SSE with reciprocal/multiplication method
    // 38.5 seconds for SSE with division method
    // 301.5 seconds for CPU

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `_aligned_malloc` for either C or C++, but note that it's Microsoft-specific.

Comment: I'm using GCC, mingw though?

Comment: In that case use the more portable `memalign`/`posix_memalign` family of calls - there are several related questions with good answers on StackOverflow already.

Comment: I thought those were for C though?

Comment: Sure - but that does not prevent you using them in C++.

Comment: I've looked but haven't found a single example for this problem with SSE.

Comment: Because it is not specific to SSE.

Comment: Well here's a fantastic answer that even includes a suitable cross-platform wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12055862/253056 - there are plenty of other questions and answers covering this topic though.

Comment: I think it's this `float *pResult;
  posix_memalign(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pResult), 16, length * sizeof(float));` from http://jeffmatherphotography.com/dispatches/2012/02/an-experiment-with-sse/

Comment: `_mm_malloc` and `_mm_free `are cross-platform versions of aligned allocation/deallocation for SSE/AVX computations. They should be available in any x86 compiler supporting SSE instrinsics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with C++11, you may use something like:

```
struct aligned_float
{
    alignas(16) float f[4];
};

static_assert(sizeof(aligned_float) == 4 * sizeof(float), "padding issue");

int main()
{
    const int length = 64000;
    std::vector<aligned_float> pResult(length / sizeof(aligned_float));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<T>` and `new` don't actually respect over-aligned alignment requirements (at least not in C++11 or C++14.  Maybe changing later).  This will happen to work on most x86-64 systems because the allocator already returns 16B-aligned memory by default.

Answer (score 1):

The aligned attributes only apply to how things are compiled/linked. It has no runtime effect.

The only portable way I know to solve this, is to have a wrapper that actually allocates more than is necessary, and masks off the lower bits to ensure that what it returs meets a ssufficient alignment.

Comment: I guess I just need it for GCC though. The simplest answer would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

See here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html

Glibc provides aligned_alloc().